# Were 70 COVID-19 testing sites destroyed during the George Floyd protests?

Tags: united-states, covid-19

> Dr. Deborah Birx, President Trump’s coronavirus response coordinator, warned the nation’s governors on a conference call that 70 coronavirus testing sites had been destroyed amid widespread protests in the wake of the death of George Floyd.

[Source](https://news.yahoo.com/dr-birx-says-george-floyd-151449109.html?soc_src=community&soc_trk=fb)

It sounds mildly plausible in that there have been some businesses which have had windows smashed or which have been set on fire, and there's bound to be some pharmacies and medical test facilities among them, if for no other reason than that fires spread, but on the other hand, it's a claim being made without any real sources.

Comment: It needs to be noted that this claim does not appear to limit the scope of the destruction to just the US.  There were large protests in many nations.

Comment: This https://www.thedailybeast.com/trumps-task-force-warns-governors-of-covid-spike-tied-to-protests has made the leaked call available. I haven't listened to it all the way through.

Comment: Gave it a quick listen and it seems pretty unsourced. I mean, I guess it kind of makes sense, that you wouldn't be providing your sources in a conference call, but yeah...

Comment: At 19:48 in the 6/3 recording Birx says "We know a lot of testing sites were compromised in these neighborhoods".  At 20:50 Pence says "Sadly, that has impacted ... facilities where people are doing testing".  Did not find the claim of 70 sites destroyed.  If it's present I suspect it's in the Q&A section.

Comment: @DanielRHicks At 45:17 in this recording https://soundcloud.com/the-daily-beast-politics/coronavirustaskforce69 she says 70, and a little later someone says 4 of the 70 are pharmacies in Washington DC owned by a single Maryland family.

Comment: In Philidelphia alone, over 150 pharmacies were looted.  https://whyy.org/articles/philly-pharmacies-reeling-rebuilding-after-more-than-a-third-were-looted/

Comment: Although, as noted in the article, a number of the cases look more like planned robberies than opportunistic smashes or grabs.

Comment: @SeanDuggan She doesn't directly couple the word "destroyed" with the number "70".  She says a significant number were destroyed, and then says "and we did lose a significant, I think 70 testing sites that were in urban areas".

Comment: The quote that DavePhD found could be explained by e.g. 70 testing sites being closed because the workers went to the protests instead of showing up for work, or not being able to get to work because the protest route runs between their home and their place of work. It doesn't even have to be workers at the testing facilities, it could be that all 70 rely on the same supplier and that one has shut down. There are other explanations for "losing" a testing site than it being "destroyed".

Comment: Are these sites for collecting samples? Like the drive-in sites. This is what I understood "testing sites" to mean, but the question and some comments imply facilities that test samples would be included. Not saying one interpretation is correct, just wondering about the meaning.

Comment: @AzorAhai yes, like drive-up collection sites.  This explains 3 of the sites that were later put out of commission, at least temporarily, by the looting: https://hillrag.com/2020/05/12/grubbs-pharmacies-to-offer-covid-19-testing/ and a nice photo here: https://georgetowner.com/articles/2020/05/14/morgan-pharmacy-opens-covid-19-testing/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a [recording](https://soundcloud.com/the-daily-beast-politics/coronavirustaskforce69) of a conference call Brix says a significant number were destroyed, and then says "and we did lose a significant, I think 70 testing sites that were in urban areas".  She specifies that these are mainly pharmacies.

Then Pence (?) says that he met with the Maryland family who owns 4 of the 70, which are located in DC.

These 4 pharmacies are:

> Grubbs NE Capitol Hill
> Grubbs NW Dupont
> Grubbs SE Anacostia
> Morgan’s Pharmacy Georgetown

owned by Michael and Joan Kim.  These owners put out a [statement](https://www.gofundme.com/f/jys3yx-support-dc-small-business-owners?utm_source=customer&utm_medium=copy_link&utm_campaign=m_pd%20share-sheet) 3 June 2020:

> Wanted to let people know that we resumed the COVID19 testing at our Capitol Hill location today

The link also has photos of the damage.

The buildings were damaged, but not anywhere close to completely destroyed.

For more information see the Washington post article [Scores of testing sites forced to close because of vandalism in civil unrest](https://www.washingtonpost.com/health/scores-of-testing-sites-forced-to-close-because-of-vandalism-in-civil-unrest/2020/06/03/e6d9fa54-a4e6-11ea-b473-04905b1af82b_story.html)

> The 70 testing sites — out of 424 in the program — that closed because of unrest are in 17 states, plus the District. They include four Rite Aids in Philadelphia and four Walgreens in Chicago.

So on the one hand, "destroyed" isn't the best term, it is more like "put out of commission", but on the other hand the 70 is just from one federal program. It shouldn't be interpreted as only 70 testing sites put out of commission.

Comment: Being closed is not the same as being "put out of commission," either. My neighborhood CVS boarded up and closed early one day due to rumors that a planned March was going to lead to vandalism.

Comment: @jeffronicus the Washington Post says "70 such sites across the country that had to close because of destruction from civil unrest", so I don't think just closing early one day would be included in the 70.

Comment: Point noted. It would help to see how HHS characterized the closures, which I don't find on their website. An NBC story from June 2 at https://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-news/protesting-pandemic-covid-19-testing-sites-shut-down-amid-national-n1222131talks about centers in Florida closing because the National Guard members running them were reassigned to deal with unrest, and LA County listed 14 sites that were closed June 1 due to the "State of Emergency" and/or curfews: https://covid19.lacounty.gov/covid19-news/update-on-county-run-covid-19-testing-sites/

Comment: That is, were 70 sites closed due to damage -- and other sites were closed for unrest-related reasons -- or were 70 sites closed due to unrest-related reasons, in some cases due to vandalism/damage/destruction?

Comment: @jeffronicus I don't think any of the 14 closed June 1st in Los Angles count toward the 70, because none of those are part of the 424 in the HHS Community free testing program.  https://www.hhs.gov/coronavirus/community-based-testing-sites/index.html

Comment: It would be interesting to find out how many are closed simply because of the chaos in the area, as opposed to taking damage that would force them to be unable to deliver service. Unfortunately DavePhD can't retroactively fix the sloppy use of mixed/match/conflation in the linked stories.

Comment: I think your answer is sufficient unless we get new facts.